# What does 0<&- &>> mean in BASH script?

Tags: bash

I am looking at a BASH script for which I don't understand this portion.

```
some_command arg1 arg2 0<&- &>> $LOGDIR/component.log &
```

What does `0<&- &>>`  do?

How is this different from

```
some_command arg1 arg2 2>&1 >> $LOGDIR/component.log &
```

Comment: Bash scripts really do appear to be "write-only" lol

Comment: `descriptor<&-` means to to close that descriptor

Comment: There has to be duplicates of this, but you can't search for `<&-` in SO.

Comment: Read the section on redirections in the bash manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html

Comment: Order matters: `>file 2>&1` and `2>&1 >file` are different. (The former makes both FD 1 and FD 2 point to `file`; the latter makes FD 2 point to the _prior_ destination of FD 1, and only FD 1 point to `file`)

Answer (score 1):

- `0<&-` is POSIX-standardized syntax that closes stdin, causing any attempt to read from it to fail with an error indicating that the file descriptor is invalid.

  This is generally bad practice, and `</dev/null` (which provides an end-of-file indication when read from) should be used instead.
- `&>>dest` is a bash extension that redirects *both* stdout and stderr to a single file descriptor that appends to `dest`. It is thus equivalent to the POSIX-standard syntax `>>dest 2>&1`

Comment: Are you suggesting I replace "0<&-" with "0</dev/null" ?

Comment: Yes, I do indeed suggest that to reduce the chance of your program reporting fatal errors when it tries to read from stdin. Or just `</dev/null` alone; there's no reason for the `0`, as stdin -- 0 -- is the default FD used by `<`.